# how to set up pdfkit

Tags: python, pdfkit

I am trying to use pdfkit but have trouble with the configuration set up on my mac.
I have not used it before thus my question here:

- installed pdfkit with pip command
- specified the configuration with my path to the location of .../wkhtmltopdf
- after execting the cell I get the error:

  `OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wkhtmltopdf/"` `If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf`

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: are you using anaconda?

Comment: or any environment?

Comment: and which python version you are using, if you are using python 3.7 in that case according to https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/ work on python 3.3 or less